# Excel, duplicates in string, single cell iteration

Tags: regex, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to extract certain pieces of data from a very long string within a single cell. For the sake of this exercise, this is the data I have in cell A1.

> a:2:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:5:{s:4:"uenc";s:252:"WN0aW9uYWwuaHRlqdyZ2dC1hdD0lN0JhZHR5cGUlN0QmdnQtcHRpPSU3QmFkd29yZHNfcHJvZHVjdHRhcmdldGlkJTdEJiU3Qmlnbm9y,";s:7:"product";s:4:"1253";s:8:"form_key";s:16:"wyfg89N";s:7:"options";a:6:{i:10144;s:5:"73068";i:10145;s:5:"63085";i:10141;s:5:"73059";i:10143;s:5:"73064";i:13340;s:5:"99988";i:10142;s:5:"73063";}s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";}s:7:"options";a:6:{i:0;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:5:"Color";s:5:"value";s:11:"White";s:11:"print_value";s:11:"White";s:9:"option_id";s:5:"10144";s:11:"option_type";s:9:"drop_down";s:12:"option_value";s:5:"73068";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}i:1;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:4:"Trim";s:5:"value";s:11:"Black";s:11:"print_value";s:11:"Black";s:9:"option_id";s:5:"10145";s:11:"option_type";s:9:"drop_down";s:12:"option_value";s:5:"63085";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}i:2;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Material";s:5:"value";s:15:"Vinyl";s:11:"print_value";s:15:"Vinyl";s:9:"option_id";s:5:"10141";s:11:"option_type";s:9:"drop_down";s:12:"option_value";s:5:"73059";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}i:3;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Orientation";s:5:"value";s:17:"Left Side";s:11:"print_value";s:17:"Left Side";s:9:"option_id";s:5:"10143";s:11:"option_type";s:9:"drop_down";s:12:"option_value";s:5:"73064";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}i:4;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:12:"Table";s:5:"value";s:16:"YES! Add Table";s:11:"print_value";s:16:"YES! Add Table";s:9:"option_id";s:5:"13340";s:11:"option_type";s:9:"drop_down";s:12:"option_value";s:5:"99988";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}i:5;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:8:"Shipping";s:5:"value";s:20:"Front Door Delivery";s:11:"print_value";s:20:"Front Door Delivery";s:9:"option_id";s:5:"10142";s:11:"option_type";s:9:"drop_down";s:12:"option_value";s:5:"73063";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}}}

The end result, would be to separate the values for Color, Trim, Material Orientation, etc.

The formula I was using is this:

```
=MID(LEFT(A4,FIND("print_value",A4)-9),FIND("Color",A4)+25,LEN(A4))
```

This basically looks in between two points and trims out the fat. It works, but only for the first iteration of "print_value". If I were to use this searching for "Trim"...

```
=MID(LEFT(A4,FIND("print_value",A4)-9),FIND("Trim",A4)+25,LEN(A4))
```

...I get an empty result. This happens because print_value is duplicate and not unique to the string. Excel doesn't understand what point to apply its function to and poops itself.

Even though there are unique factors within this string that I could essentially attach myself to (and arrive at the desired result), I CAN NOT use them as they will not be consistent and will render the formula useless when applied to other cells.

That said, here is what I need. Within this formula, I need a way to either A) tell the formula which iteration of print_value to find or B) change print_value to print_value(1,2,3,4, etc) and then run my trimming formula.

Comment: You have not defined your requirements clearly enough to use Regex. But, for example, if you run a Regex looking for `print_value` against your data, you will get a match collection of six items that start with `print_value` and it is trivial to return whichever of those you want, or whichever part of it you want.  Again, in your example, there are ZERO instances of the word `Color` that follows any instance of `print_value`

Answer (score 0):

Few options based on this [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1052-excel-find-nth-occurrence.html):

**1) VBA - Using a User Defined Function**
If you're new to these then follow this [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel).

```
Function FindN(sFindWhat As String, _
sInputString As String, N As Integer) As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Application.Volatile
FindN = 0
For J = 1 To N
FindN = InStr(FindN + 1, sInputString, sFindWhat)
If FindN = 0 Then Exit For
Next
End Function
```

**2) Using a Formula**

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"c",CHAR(1),3))
```

- c is the character you want to find
- A1 is the text you want to look in
- 3 is the nth instance